# mingw linker can't find PathAppend

Tags: linker, mingw

When I try to compile the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  char firstPart[MAX_PATH] = "c:\\windows";
  char secondPart[MAX_PATH] = "system32";
  PathAppend(firstPart, secondPart);

  return 0;
}
```

Using the command:

```
c:\mingw\bin\gcc -mwindows -mno-cygwin -o test test.c
```

It fails with the error:

> undefined reference to ``_imp__PathAppendA@8'`

Surely this is some stupidity on my part, but can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the shlwapi library for linking:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lshlwapi
```

Works for me

Comment: Perfect! I had tried using the -lshlwapi before the filenames, but I guess it goes after.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. It is a toolchain bug IMO: the order of options should not matter in this case. Using gcc on linux does not have this problem. Looking at gcc -v, I can see that the -lshlwapi is simply ignored when put before test.c. Maybe recent gcc (4.4 serie) do not have those problems.

Comment: Sorry, I means 4.* serie. The officially released mingw gcc is ancient (3.4 serie) - if that's an option, you should use more recent, either by compiling it yourself, or using available binary out there.

Comment: @DavidCournapeau It's not a toolchain bug. The "-l" option for gcc has always meant "resolve symbols which are unresolved at this point from the given library (by pulling in any modules which define these symbols into the link)". In the case of shared libraries on some systems (eg Linux) this pulls in the whole library so order becomes unimportant, but for static linking it always matters (and linking against a DLL on Windows is a special case of static linking, since you are actually linking against a set of import stubs).

Comment: I tried the -shlwapi and it changed nothing for me.