# error with PathFindFileName when compiling under mingw

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw

code:

```
#include <shlwapi.h>
int main() {
  TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
  DWORD bufSize;
  GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, bufSize);
  TCHAR* out = PathFindFileName(buffer);
}
```

error message:

```
ccQzTh4t.o:pathfind.cpp:(.text.startup+0x40): undefined reference to `_imp__PathFindFileNameA@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe I forgot some includes ?

Comment: what you have is a linker error. probably you forget to link relevant library.

Comment: I guess it's probably `-lShlwapi` you need.

Comment: `fatal error: lshlwapi: No such file or directory`

Comment: Note the `-` in front of the command-line option, Rsk82. It's the `-l` option followed by the name of the library to link with.

Comment: can I do that from source file and not from command line ?

Comment: Some integrated compiler-linkers provide non-standard ways to do that (e.g. `#pragma comment(lib, ...)`, but it's generally a bad idea. The header file is for the compiler, the library is for the linker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PathFindFileName` is part of the `Shlwapi.lib` library, you need to link against it.

Comment: But how, isn't it?: `#include <shlwapi.h>`

Comment: @rsk82: That's an inclusion of a header file, different of an inclusion of a library at link time.

Comment: That includes the *declarations* of the functions, Rsk82. The compiler doesn't automatically know where the *definitions* are. To the compiler, what's in that header look like ordinary function declarations, just like functions you might declare yourself. The *linker* is what's in charge of figuring out where to find the implementations of all the functions the compiler saw your program use. The `-l` option tells your build system to look in the given library for implementations that weren't included in the main program text.

Comment: thanks for the answers, the thing is also that this param goes after file names at the very end of parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/623270/393087